# RegEx - prefix + input value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have `input` and I would like to achieve to always have in value prefix `+34` and value typed by user which consist of 9 digits

I have tried somethign like this

```
let val = value.replace(/[^\d]{9}/g, "+34{1}");
```

but it does not work, any idea what I am doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple string concatenation is enough for this.

```
let val = '+34' + value;
```

---

In your current code, it's actually removing entire 9 digits with the string
(`"+34{1}"`). To refer the [match in replace string you can use `$&` in that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

```
let val = value.replace(/^\d{9}/, "+34$&");
```

Or alternatively use [positive look-ahead in the regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert the position where you want to insert.

```
let val = value.replace(/^(?=\d{9})/, "+34");
```

Comment: agreed, though i'm very curious why this was the first method they came up with.

Comment: @Marker :  no idea :)

Comment: nice solution, thank you @PranavCBalan, but is it possible to hide prefix `+34` and store it in `input` value ??

Comment: @JustJSFan : you can have a hidden input field for that..... for showing  in iput, use some css...  ( `::before` can be use)